# Crystax usage with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, gradle

I have tried the Crystax sample on IDEA, and I have compiled it successfully, got it to run on my phone.

However, when I try to modify the project, IDEA throws an error about Gradle version:

**Error:The project is using an incompatible version of the Android Gradle "experimental" plugin.
Please update your project to use version 0.9.0.**

Then I updated it and met new problems:

**Gradle version 3.3 is required. Current version is 4.1.**

**Please fix the project's Gradle settings.**

I choose to *Fix Gradle wrapper and re-import project*

Then the next error appears:

**Cannot set readonly property: proguardFiles for class: com.android.build.gradle.managed.BuildType**

Please, is there anyone who knows how to use Crystax on IDEA IDE?

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative way, which does not relies on AS to build.

Just set your system PATH to Crystax-ndk folder, set up your Application.mk and Android.mk, and run command:

```
ndk-build
```

then you will get the result lib or executable file, then, link it to your Android project.